# %python.sql interpreter not found in zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

i made a data using python interpreter in zeppelin.
but, it has many rows and i want to download in own computer.

so i find a method in apache zeppelin page

> https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/python.html#sql-over-pandas-dataframes

after the read a page, i download pandas and pandasql library in a zeppelin server.

and i also follow the page which is next paragraph.
datas is python dataframe type.

```
%python.sql
select *from datas
```

but it has a error

```
 python.sql interpreter not found
```

so , how i can a fix it??..
if you know a solution, plz tell me how

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of zeppelin do you use ? Please try to use the latest version (0.7.3)

Comment: Thanks, , now i know my zeppelin version is not a 0.7.3 
after i will update zeppelin version , i checked it!

Comment: now i use zeppelin (0.7.3), but '%sql' it has continuously error that is Interpreter sql not found.

Comment: please use '%python.sql' instead of '%sql'

Comment: also has a error ..python.sql interpreter not found

Comment: could you stop zeppelin first and then delete file conf/interpreter.json, restart zeppelin again ?

Answer (score 0):

You can print your dataframe as table by

```
print('%table ' + df.to_csv(sep='\t'))
```

Comment: df has a many rows ,  print('df'), it is skip the partial data